# Nvd3- is it possible to display any string value at x-axis at nvd3 line / bar chart?

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 chart library to display charts in my application.I used to show many chart types say line,bar,pie,scatter,etc..
Till now ,i used to show only integer/float values at x-axis of line/bar chart chart..Its working well.(Sample data : (x-10, y-50),(x-20, y-100))
But the problem is,when am trying to display the line chart with some string value at x-axis,the nvd3 chart doesn't display anything..Dont know where am going wrong?
(sample data : (x-sun,y-50),(x-mon,y-75),(x-tue,y-100))
Need help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: No dude..But am getting NAN instead of x-axis string.Also getting NAN at tooltip..

Comment: It sounds like you're using dates for the x axis. It would be better to pass in those values as dates, parse them and let D3 format the axis labels for you.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: No,i didnt try to pass dates into x-axis.iam trying to pass just string as shown in my question..ie.(sample data : (x-sun,y-50),(x-mon,y-75),(x-tue,y-100))

Comment: Can you post your JSON data and some code? You might need to change the axis from a linear scale, otherwise it might be trying to interpolate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

select all the svg element that corresponds to text. container is a variable referring a string for selection of text;

```
d3.selectAll(container + ' .nv-x .tick text').text(function(d){return d;})
```